# Integrando WebService C# com android

Tags: c#, android, json

Estou com um Web Service Feito em C# porem não consigo consumi-lo no `Android`. Segue o Código do `android` e o `LogCat`.

```
//----------------------------- Conectando a Base WS

class asynProjeto extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
        dialogo = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogo.setMessage("Carregando");
        dialogo.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        dialogo.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){

        //super.onPostExecute(s);
        dialogo.dismiss();
        if(s.equals("ok")){
            carregarHello();
        }else {
            Log.e("Script", "Deu Errado:" + s);
        }
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings){


        if (Hello()){
            return "Ok";
        }else{
            return "erro";
        }
    }
```

E essa é a exceção:

> 02-03 14:34:54.604 3372-3398/com.example.cpires.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>
> Process: com.example.cpires.myapplication, PID: 3372
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljavax/microedition/io/Connector;
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionMidp.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.getServiceConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.call(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity.Hello(MainActivity.java:129)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity$asynProjeto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity$asynProjeto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "javax.microedition.io.Connector" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.cpires.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.cpires.myapplication-2/lib/x86,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                           at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionMidp.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.getServiceConnection(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                           at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.call(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity.Hello(MainActivity.java:129) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity$asynProjeto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.cpires.myapplication.MainActivity$asynProjeto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.microedition.io.Connector
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                 ... 13 more
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: Cara, tente direcionar para a parte do código que você acha que está o problema...

Comment: A URL que você está usando (`http://localhost:2749/Service.asmx?WSDL`) é o endereço da **descrição** do web service (WSDL), e não do serviço em si (que deve ser a mesma URL, sem o `?WSDL`).

Comment: Eu não entendo a negativação na pergunta do cara... ta faltando um pouco de qualidade e percepção da parte de quem quer responder... de uma olhada na minha resposta e vê se ajudou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android SDK nao da o provider do javax.microedition.io. De uma olhada em [Package Index](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Esta faltando esse provider pelo que percebi no erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljavax/**microedition**/io/Connector; at
>   org.**ksoap2**.transport.ServiceConnectionMidp.(**Unknown Source**)

Acredito que voce tenha que baixar o pacote ksoap2:
[ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

OBS: Verifique sempre a versão mais recente do ksoap2.